# Firefox frequently hanging, but no Javascript? Browser environment corrupted?

Tags: firefox, performance, browser, javascript

Recently my browser (Firefox latest version) has been hanging when visiting heavily commercialized sites even though I have Javascript and YouTube and other programmatic features disabled. How can a site be hanging my browser if Javascript is turned off? Here is an example site:

http://foreignpolicy.com/2016/03/30/erdogan-uses-closed-door-meeting-to-blast-white-house/

UPDATE

I think the answers are basically right in that this is caused by a temporary issue in the browser memory basically being corrupted and trying to access some kind of old content.

When I restart the browser, even with exactly the same tabs/pages loaded, the browser is responsive, so this suggests that the memory state of the browser has some problematic object or element in it that is causing the slowdown and the solution is just to restart.

Comment: With the page open, you can go to Web Developer - Network window (from the menu or Ctrl+Shift+Q). Click on Reload and you can see what is loading along with loading time. I don't know what the "other programmatic features" are, but Flash Player and Web Fonts are high on my troublesome list. You might also add your OS in your question, though it may not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely to be the browser *per se*. Try the following:

1. Update to the latest version [45.0.1 at this writing]
2. [Clear the browser cache](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic#firefox), in case you're short on space. E.G. on the *History* menu, select *Clear recent history...* and choose at least *Cache*.
3. Restart in *Safe* mode, either from *Help*, *Restart with Add-ons Disabled*, or by creating a shortcut with **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -safe-mode* as the target (or other location).

If browsing is still slow, it might be your network connection or PC; the page cited opened in less than 3 seconds in Firefox when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox should not be hanging, it could be an extension or an unusual plug-in that's causing it, start by disabling your extensions.